# Number combination which brings different result in sum

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I am looking for 6 numbers which when added their sum should not be a repeated no like one below for 3 Numbers

```
    Num 1   Num 2    Num 3         Sum 
      1       3        5            9 
      1       0        5            6
      0       3        5            8 
      0       0        5            5
      1       3        0            4
      1       0        0            1
      0       3        0            3
      0       0        0            0
```

Adding 1,3,5 in any combination leaving other is not going to get the same sum like adding 1,2,3 which brings 6 for 0+1+2 and 0+0+3

I want this number for a programming logic which i am going to use in procedure

Just let me know whether its possible or not.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Let me know whether this is possible or not

Comment: Take any two numbers $0<a<b$ as the first two. Take any $c>a+b$ as the third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. If you take the $n$ numbers $1,2,2^2,\dots,2^{n-1}$, no sum will be repeated. This includes "sums" of just $1$ of the numbers, and even the "empty sum" of none of the numbers.